# How to set the default format in dayjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dayjs

I want set "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" to the default format to avoid unnecessary code like:

```
this.dayjs().startOf("year").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
this.dayjs().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
this.dayjs().startOf("week").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below to App.vue,

```
created() {
  this.$dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way, by overwriting the default format method in a plugin:

```js
const defaultFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'

dayjs.extend((option, dayjsClass, dayjsFactory) => {
  const oldFormat = dayjsClass.prototype.format

  dayjsClass.prototype.format = function (formatString) {
    return oldFormat.bind(this)(formatString ?? defaultFormat)
  }
})
```

Modified example from https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/plugin

After using this plugin the custom default format will now be applied when you call `.format()` without any parameters.